# jQuery .on() delegating and the 'this' value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a script and it has run into some problems:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        iH: function() {
            $(document).on('mouseenter', this, function(e) {
                alert('this is the element');
            })
        }
    })
})(jQuery);​
```

then in the body:

```
$(function(){
    $('.elem').iH();
});

<div class="elem">element</div>
```

I have created a fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/willisilliw/8SdDe/)

Basically, any ideas how to make the actual element `this` be the `this` element in the callback function?

Also, I do not want to use `.live()` or `.delegate()` as they have been depreciated.

**EDIT:**

The reason I wam trying to do this is because I am trying to bind elements that might not already exist in the DOM, IE I could do this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        iH: function() {
            $(this).on('mouseenter', function(e) {
                alert('this is the element');
            })
            $(this).live('mouseenter', function(e) {
                alert('Depreciated LIVE function');
            })
        }
    })
})(jQuery);​
```

however it would not trigger for any elements that are added after the event is bound, but `.live()` would trigger it:

```
$('body').append($('<div />').addClass('elem').html('content'));
$('.elem').iH();
$('body').append($('<div />').addClass('elem').html('content'));
```

Like I said, `.live()` has been depreciated so I am trying not to use it.

updated fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/willisilliw/8SdDe/6/)

**CLARIFICATION FOR FUTURE REFERENCE**

Since the (correct) answer was given, it transpired that the problem was in fact that I was passing a jQuery object to the function. Upon further investigation I discovered that you could, indeed, use the `this` variable inside the function to point to the affected element(s):

```
$.fn.extend({
    iH: function() {
        $(document).on('mouseenter', this.selector, function(e) {
            alert($(this).html());
        });
    }
})

$('.elem').iH();
$('body').append('<div class="elem">Value</div>')​
```

Demo: [jsFiddle #3](http://jsfiddle.net/willisilliw/8SdDe/12/)

Comment: I don't understand... What is the problem? The fiddle seems to work fine

Comment: it's only supposed to trigger when you mouse-over the div element

Comment: @AndrewWillis The callback that you have defined is triggered only when you mouse-over the div element, but the mouse enter event bound to the document object and it is still triggered whenever mouse enters the document.

Comment: I understand that, I have updated my question with more info, basically my problem would arise when the element is generated after the event is bound. jQuery claim that .on() can replace .live() but it does not appear so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I think I understood your problem. The code seems to work fine in FF but not in IE. The second argument in `.on` is a selector and it is not working fine when you use `this` object(at least in IE).

Try using `$(this).selector` instead of `this`. See below,

Updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8SdDe/7/)

```
$.fn.extend({
    iH: function() {
        $(document).on('mouseenter', $(this).selector, function(e) {
            alert(e.target.className);
        });
    }
})

$('.elem').iH();
```

---

The behavior is correct and `this` object inside the function is the `document` object, because the mouse event is bound the `document` object. However if you want the `div` element, then you need to use `e.target`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/8SdDe/1/)

Comment: The event doesn't trigger when you mouse over the element still, only on the document, which is what i am trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewWillis I think I understood the problem, Check my edits or Try http://jsfiddle.net/8SdDe/7/

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$.fn.extend({
  iH: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(document).on('mouseenter', $(this).selector, function(e) {
      var $el = $(this);
      alert('this is the element: ' + $el.html());
    })
  }
});

$('.elem').iH();
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/XhXSx/)

Comment: I have updated my question as I missed out an important part of the problem, to do with elements added to the document dynamically.

Comment: Thankyou, you were just a little late! I +1'd you cos your answer was right!